# How can I refactoring nested if/elif python panda pivot table code using openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, openpyxl

When I started this was supposed to be a quick 7 day pivot table.  Then it moved to a monthly report and I kept building code on it to automate our views with color coding and a percentage after the totals.  I've tried to refactor in a couple ways and I just can't see it, I'm probably approaching this entirely wrong so I'm hoping someone out there can help me.  This report can have Grand Totals in any row from 11-15 (after I do the reshaping of the totals to the bottom.) I go from 28 days to 31 days using the columns 31 Days AG2, 30 Days AF2, 29 Days AE2 and 28 days AD2.  I did a bunch of nested if's thinking this wouldn't turn into anything.  Now I need some help refactoring if just to have a direction to move in, I've tried a few different ways but I always seem to make it more messy.  Here is an example of just 31 days. Any advice would be much appreciated, I modify a dataframe to get the output to the pivot table.

```
    # 31 Days for the Month - Sheet name is Totals
    if Totals['AG2'].value == "Grand Totals":
        if Totals['A15'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH2'] = 'Percent'
            Totals['AH3'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH4'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH5'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH6'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH7'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH8'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH9'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH10'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH11'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH12'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH12'] = '=AG12/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH13'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH13'] = '=AG13/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH14'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH14'] = '=AG14/$AG$15'
            # Color coding inside the pivot table
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('B3:AF14', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                        mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))
            # Color coding for the percent column.
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('AH3:AH14', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                         mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))

        elif Totals['A14'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH2'] = 'Percent'
            Totals['AH3'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH4'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH5'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH6'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH7'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH8'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH9'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH10'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH11'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH12'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH12'] = '=AG12/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH13'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH13'] = '=AG13/$AG$14'
            Totals.delete_rows(15, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('B3:AF13', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                        mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('AH3:AH13', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                         mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))

        elif Totals['A13'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH2'] = 'Percent'
            Totals['AH3'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH4'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH5'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH6'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH7'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH8'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH9'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH10'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH11'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH12'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH12'] = '=AG12/$AG$13'
            Totals.delete_rows(14, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('B3:AF12', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                        mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('AH3:AH12', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                         mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))

        elif Totals['A12'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH2'] = 'Percent'
            Totals['AH3'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH4'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH5'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH6'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH7'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH8'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH9'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH10'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH11'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$12'
            Totals.delete_rows(13, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('B3:AF11', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                        mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('AH3:AH11', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                         mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))

        elif Totals['A11'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH2'] = 'Percent'
            Totals['AH3'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH4'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH5'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH6'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH7'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH8'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH9'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH10'].number_format = '0.0%'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$11'
            Totals.delete_rows(12, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('B3:AF10', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                        mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add('AH3:AH10', ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571',
                                                                         mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59'))
```

My imports to give an idea of what I'm working with.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Font
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScale, ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
```

Comment: Most of the code looks the same in the different branches, so you can probably simplify that. Then it will probably be easier to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I'm manually figuring out which day the month ends on, because when I tried to loop through and find the last blank space, Python wouldn't trigger on that.  So I noticed that in the month there was a Grand Totals.  I also noticed when I re-ordered the totals to the bottom I could find Grand Totals that way.  That's how I found this answer and it works, but it's really messy.  I'm looking to refactor so it's more readable and not so much reuse of code.

Comment: This is the section I use to re-order the totals in case anyone out there needs it. `code`     # Re-orders the metrics so that they are decending and moves the Grand Total back to the bottom.
    df1 = df1.assign(sortkey=df1.index == 'Grand Totals')\
        .sort_values(by=['sortkey', 'Grand Totals'], ascending=[True, False])\
        .drop('sortkey', axis=1) `code`

Comment: Most of the code is similar, I'm manually decrementing through from 31 to 28. (Also doing the same in the rows.)  I'm just not sure the methodology for how to refactor this code in python.  Why I say that is I wrote a "connector" for SQL months later I found out there is a module that does all that work.  I'm hoping, there is already a module out there I'm unaware of that automatically resizes the pivot table and thus the heat charts along side it.  I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: It's fairly easy to create a table of variable length using openpyxl. If you can simplify the question, it will be easier to answer.

Comment: I have the nested ifs and I would like to refactor the code so that I'm using functions.  I have many tabs, this is a single tab and I limit most to top 20.  I would like a base code that's more of a template than these nested ifs.  I have a feeling I'm just missing the syntax.  Still watching tons of refactoring videos for recursion but I can't wrap my mind around it.  I've tried to turn each sheet into their own function but it seems to blow up even larger in size code wise.

Comment: The code works, so I would say I'm trying to get more at where to start on refactoring something that is so obviously ugly.  It's easy to understand but I know the code can be reduced.  I'm just not sure where to go next.  Any direction would be appreciated, I don't need an answer, I plan on finding that .. I haven't been able to do what I need in openpyxl my blindness could be there but so far I've done a lot of handling and months static or my rows has been my dead end.  Thanks, I appreciate you responding.

Comment: It seems to me you just need to adjust the column length. Why don't use a variable for that? BTW. CodeExchange is the site to discuss refactoring.

Comment: This isn't the entire code, I'm limited by what I can share.  I cycle through all the sheets doing formatting.  I wanted to get closer to "pythonic" code since I'm fairly new in the sense of taking python seriously.  I'm trying to revisit my CS classes and head more object oriented.  My end goal would be to completely automate spreadsheets based on my companies dbs, but I automate views with python and send the rawdata out in zipped form.  So far this covers everything, I just want to make the code look readable to others not just to me. lol  Thanks for the response. I'm still refactoring.

Comment: Like I said, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I did some refactoring, one of my issues was I couldn't find out how to cycle through columns and change a series of columns into a percentage.  This isn't everything but I hope this helps someone out there, I'm going to keep working towards something very lean.
I had to add a few imports as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Font
from openpyxl.styles.numbers import NumberFormat
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScale, ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule, DifferentialStyle, Rule
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
```

As before this is 31 days.

```
    Totals = wb['Totals']
    Totals['A2'] = 'Totals'

    # This code sets Red/Yellow/Green pattern for both the table and percentages columns.
    setTableColorPattern = ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=10, start_color='54C571', mid_type='percentile',
                                          mid_value=50, mid_color='FFF380', end_type='percentile', end_value=90, end_color='F75D59')

    # This section matches 31 days at AG2, the nested if/elif cover the varing row lengths.
    if Totals['AG2'].value == "Grand Totals":
        Totals['AH2'] = 'Percent'

        diff_style = DifferentialStyle(
            numFmt=NumberFormat(numFmtId='4', formatCode='0.0%'))
        rule1 = Rule(type="expression", dxf=diff_style)
        rule1.formula = ["=NOT(ISBLANK($AG2))"]
        # provide a range of cells to change to percent.
        Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
            "$AH3:$AH14", rule1)

        if Totals['A7'].value == "Grand Totals":
            # Setting Column Name to Percent.
            # Creating the Percent column with each row divided into the total.
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$7'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$7'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$7'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$7'
            Totals.delete_rows(8, 0)
            # Setting the color pattern for the main table.
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF6', setTableColorPattern)
            # Setting the color pattern for the Percent column.
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH6', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A8'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$8'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$8'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$8'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$8'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$8'
            Totals.delete_rows(9, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF7', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH7', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A9'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$9'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$9'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$9'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$9'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$9'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$9'
            Totals.delete_rows(10, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF8', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH8', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A10'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$10'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$10'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$10'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$10'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$10'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$10'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$10'
            Totals.delete_rows(11, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF9', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH9', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A11'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$11'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$11'
            Totals.delete_rows(12, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF10', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH10', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A12'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$12'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$12'
            Totals.delete_rows(13, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF11', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH11', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A13'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$13'
            Totals['AH12'] = '=AG12/$AG$13'
            Totals.delete_rows(14, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF12', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH12', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A14'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH12'] = '=AG12/$AG$14'
            Totals['AH13'] = '=AG13/$AG$14'
            Totals.delete_rows(15, 0)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF13', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH13', setTableColorPattern)

        elif Totals['A15'].value == "Grand Totals":
            Totals['AH3'] = '=AG3/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH4'] = '=AG4/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH5'] = '=AG5/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH6'] = '=AG6/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH7'] = '=AG7/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH8'] = '=AG8/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH9'] = '=AG9/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH10'] = '=AG10/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH11'] = '=AG11/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH12'] = '=AG12/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH13'] = '=AG13/$AG$15'
            Totals['AH14'] = '=AG14/$AG$15'
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'B3:AF14', setTableColorPattern)
            Totals.conditional_formatting.add(
                'AH3:AH14', setTableColorPattern)
```

Now to start working on each section, I'm thinking about trying to split out a function for setMonth and setRow.  I'll post up what I have. As I said, if there are any pointers out there I'm opened to any suggestions.  Thanks!